# Get Rectangle Coordinates in Canvas

Tags: typescript, canvas, frontend

This is my situation: I have a recangle drawn in the canvas. With the mouse wheel the user can zoom in and zoom out where the mouse cursor is positioned. Here is the zoom code in typescript:

```
this.context?.clearRect(
      0,
      0,
      this.width * this.CELL_SIZE,
      this.height * this.CELL_SIZE
    );
    if (event.deltaY == -100) {
      this.context?.translate(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
      this.context?.scale(1.05, 1.05);
      this.context?.translate(-event.offsetX, -event.offsetY);
    } else if (event.deltaY == 100) {
      this.context?.translate(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
      this.context?.scale(0.95, 0.95);
      this.context?.translate(-event.offsetX, -event.offsetY);
    }
    this.draw_Grid();
```

The problem is that when I scale and translate the context, the position of the rectangle change. Is there a way of getting the new rectangle position? I need to know where the new x and y coordinates of the shape starts.
After a long research I didn't find any good reply on the web.
UPDATE:
I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443310/how-to-detect-which-element-is-hovered-on-a-canvasrenderingcontext2d-with-transf) where with the mouse move you can detect the distance of the shape from the canvas border. But what I'm trying to do in my code is to automatically detect the distance of the shape after translating and zooming the context, not by mouse move event.
Here is a screenshot that can be userful to better understand what I need to obtain
[image: I need to know the distance marked with the arrows]
Any suggestion / solution will be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: The canvas is just a visual (i.e. very end-user) representation of what's behind the scenes, that is the shapes. You should bear those, instead of the pixel matrix. That's doable by creating every shape's model, and keeping its instance somewhere in the client-side. However, once you "point" the mouse, that should be adjusted accordingly to the canvas' trasformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the new position relative to the original transformation matrix by using the [`DOMMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) returned by [`ctx.getTransform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getTransform) to transform your original coordinates, with its `transformPoint()` method:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(10, 75);
ctx.scale(2.4, 1.3);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 3);
ctx.translate(-10, -75);

ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 20, 20);

const mat = ctx.getTransform();
const point = { x: 30, y: 30 }; // Top left corner of the filled rect
const trans = mat.transformPoint(point);
console.log(trans);
// Move the red rectangle to that position
document.querySelector(".witness").style.top = `${trans.y}px`
document.querySelector(".witness").style.left = `${trans.x}px`
```

```css
.witness, canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.witness {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  translate: -5px -5px; /* So it's centered */
  background: #FF0000AA;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div class=witness></div>
```